# Не выполняется файл через локальный сервер Python

Tags: python

Здравствуйте. При запуске локального сервера, используя команду

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

возникла проблема в том, что файл:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<h1>Hello world!</h1>")
```

не исполняется, в браузере просто 
высвечивается его исходный код (права на исполнение прописал несколькими способами `chmod 755 hello.py`, `chmod +x hello.py`). В чем может быть еще проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python -m http.server` по умолчанию [запускает только скрипты, лежащие в каталогах](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories) `cgi-bin` или `htbin`. Создайте один из них и переместите свой `hello.py` туда.